# How to update the state element properly in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Form from "./child/form.js";
import Details from "./child/details.js";

function App() {
const [inp, modifyInp] = useState([]);
const inputHandler = (input) => {
modifyInp((prevState) => [{ ...prevState, ...input }]);
};
console.log(inp);
return (
<div>
<Form inpHandler={inputHandler} />
<Details inputt={inp} />
</div>
);
}
export default App;
```

I am trying to update state of inp here, but it is not updating properly and insted the value is being replaced. Can anyone help me with this?`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be here:
`modifyInp((prevState) => [{ ...prevState, ...input }]);`
here `prevState` is in fact what you call `inp`, it is supposed to be an array so if your intent is to append the input to inp your are not using the spread syntax properly.

Here you are spreading prevstate into an object, then you spread input in the same object and put the result into the first element of an array and return it as the new `inp`.

It doesn't make sense.

either `inp` is indeed an array and you should do this to **append** input to this array:

```
// if input is a single element:
modifyInp((prevState) => [...prevState, input ]);

// if input is itself an array and you want to append all of its elements:
modifyInp((prevState) => [...prevState, ...input ]);
```

Or `inp` is an object and `input` too and you want to merge `input` into `inp`:

```
modifyInp((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, ...input }));
```

Comment: nitpick: you mean `spread` here, not `destructure`

Comment: I couldnt remember the word thanks :)

Comment: Further nitpick, "spread" isn't an operator, it's a [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: Respectfully in my opinion it is both. Any language being the set of syntaxes it recognizes, each being sequences of tokens, which in case of programming languages usually fall into 3 main categories: identifiers, delimiters and operators. The spread syntax requires all of them and if one would have to give the `...` token a name in a spread syntax, I think it's ok to call it the spread operator.

Comment: ...And that's why I tend to forget the three different names for something that is cognitively the same thing to me :P (only the "direction" of the data changes)
Fixing the answer anyway....

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct and there's another way of writing your function:

```js
const inputHandler = (event) => {
   //This is what I like to do most of the times.
   
   const value = event.target.value;
   modifyInp(value);
};
```

Explanation:
It takes an `event` as a parameter, typically from an input field in a web application. Inside the function, it extracts the value entered into the input field using `event.target.value` and assigns it to a variable called value. It then calls a function named `modifyInp` with value as an argument. This function is likely responsible for processing or updating the input value in some way. Overall, `inputHandler` is designed to handle input events and pass the input value to a function for further manipulation.

Comment: The thing is we don't know what the `Details` component is. And it does not seem to pass the event to the handler. And since we don't know what input is, it may not be the desired behavior to replace the value.

Comment: That said, the OP intent is not clear and your answer may still be right.

Comment: The way i see it, it might be that `Details` could be just a simple textbox. Would you mind editing your question and supply the code for `Details`?